# How to add images to survey radio buttons?

Tags: spservices, image, survey

I need to add images to each response in sharepoint 2013 survey like this:
[image]
I had no problem with question image. I just added string "image1" to question  and then in jquery switched html like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $(function () {
        $(".ms-formlabel").each(function (index) {
            var html = $(this).html();
            if (html.indexOf("image1") != -1) {

                $(this).html("<img src='https://portal.sp.corpnet.pl/witryny/ankiety/Config/images/zdjecie1-pytanie1.png'><br>1. Ten sympatyczny młody człowiek na zdjęciu to:");
            }


        });
    });
});
```

But in answers/responses I have radio buttons with labels and I am not able to use same method. Maybe there is another way.

**Solution:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ms-formbody label").each(function() {
        var kontent = $(this).html();
            if (kontent.indexOf("pytanie1-odpowiedz1") != -1) {
                $(this).html("test1");
            }
            else if (kontent.indexOf("pytanie1-odpowiedz2") != -1) {
                $(this).html("test2");
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: This link may help you: https://robdevereaux.wordpress.com/2013/08/09/how-to-add-pictures-to-a-survey/

Comment: It is close but that code replaces only title of span not label itself... I will try to modify it. I am still looking though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this link, it has SharePoint 2010 illustration, but it will give you good reference.

Please refer this link: http://sharepointkings.blogspot.in/2011/05/include-image-in-sharepoint-survey.html

Comment: Thank you for this example. It is exact solution for my problem :).

Comment: Glad to help you.